Copy binary from inside Docker container to local filesystem with docker buildx build
This is my Dockerfile
FROM archlinux:latest AS builder

RUN pacman-key --init
RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S --noconfirm gcc cmake git make zip curl pkgconf autoconf gettext automake libtool zlib
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
RUN cd aws-sdk-cpp && \
    mkdir -p build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. -DBUILD_ONLY="core" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCUSTOM_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp.git
RUN cd aws-lambda-cpp && \
    mkdir -p build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg
RUN cd zimg && \
    git submodule init graphengine && \
    git submodule update && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install

WORKDIR /opt
COPY . .
RUN cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLOG_VERBOSITY=3
RUN make
RUN make aws-lambda-package-zimg-api

FROM archlinux:latest AS api
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /opt/zimg-api.zip .
RUN cp /opt/zimg-api.zip /home/zimg-api.zip

and I try to copy /home/zimg-api.zip to the local filesystem but it does not work:
docker buildx build -f Dockerfile -t zimg-api:0.0.10 --target api --output type=local,dest=$(pwd) .
it copies the entire filesystem of the archlinux image in my local filesystem.
Any suggestion ?
Gianluca

You'd normally use a Dockerfile to create an isolated image that can run in Docker.  The docker build sequence isn't normally supposed to be able to change anything on the host system.  Dockerfile COPY always copies files from the host into the image, and not the other direction.

What you normally do with container build pipes is that you have a repository running outside of the container, that you can push the build artifacts to. Stuff like Artifactory is used for that.

One option is to create a container against your built image and copy the file out:

Build the image normally
docker create IMAGE --name NAME
docker cp NAME:/path/to/file /local/path
docker rm NAME

Where IMAGE is your image tag/id and NAME is a name to give your container.

Thanks, this is may be a valuable option. Thanks again.
